# Assigning numerical value to a column in excel to total a list in excel

Tags: excel

I am putting together our upgrade and replace list in excel. Upgrading a machine costs $x for the price of the volume licence, and replacing costs $x for the price of the new equipment. I want to assign a 'dollar' amount to the columns, and have excel take the number I put into the rows, assign that many times the dollar value, and give me the total in the end column.

Example:

> Program | Upgrade (=$25) | Replace (=$500) | Total cost (total of A and B)
>
> Math.......|........................5|...........................2|.......$1125
>
> Science..|........................2|...........................6|.......$3,050
>
> History....|......................10|...........................1|.........$750

Is this even possible in excel? I know I could assign a numerical value to text, but I'm not sure if what I'm trying to accomplish here is possible in Excel. I know it would probably be easier to do in Access, but our CEO wants it in excel, and if I don't get a formula, I have to manually add the totals up and put them in for hundreds of programs...

Comment: I wouldn't call this vba...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Upgrade cost is in B1, and Replace cost is in C1, then place this in D2 and copy down:

```
=(B2*$B$1)+(C2*$C$1)
```

If you enter something like `$500` in the 'Upgrade' cell, and the format of the cell is set to "General"  then Excel will assume that this is a currency format unless you tell it otherwise.

Alternatively you could just use plain numbers and format the cells afterwards.